# Where to store site backups?

Tags: php, backup

Say, I want to have code and db backups? Where should I store them so that if a hacker hacked my site and have access to php and mysql I could restore them. Local server does not fit. Considering third-party services (DB, Google drive) a hacker would have success to them in case he hackes a server. If you could suggest where to store third-party API credential so that a hacker could not access them I would appreciate that.

But beside that is there a way to make and store backups by a server in a safe place (so that hacker could not get them)? As I see the only way is to make backups by outer services: from another server. I could do it from my computer. But it is a wrong solution. After I finished a project I should not have access to it. And in general It is not the best solution to rely on my computer at all.

I could not find anything worth in the internet. Is there a way to securely manage backups only from a (one) working server?

Comment: The code is properly backed up in the vcs you use (ie git) so destroying the server doesn't really matter (you do use vcs, right?). Regarding backups you can only do so much. If the client has some sort of nas box or similar you could offer to set it up to ftp to the site to get db dumps, or similar. That way your server doesn't know how to connect to the cold storage.

Comment: `If you could suggest where to store third-party API credential so that a hacker could not access them I would appreciate that.` API keys are usually very easy to regenerate and invalidate, exactly for this reason.

Comment: @JimL nas box could be a variant but I want consistent solution that will work for all cases. `API keys are usually very easy to regenerate and invalidate, exactly for this reason` you mean that I could later regenerate API keys?

Comment: Well, since you aren't trusting the server you will either need to find a 3rd party service that you do trust (and register all your clients to use for backups), or you need to set up and maintain a secure backup service yourself (sounds like quite a bit of work). Yes most APIs I've seen (if not all) have easily available refresh/regenerate functionality for API keys.

Comment: @JimL As to API refreshing I know. But in case a site is hacked a hacker can get know API credentials (if code uses API then a hacker could easily get them) and then he can do whatever he wants on a cloud (for example delete all backups)

Comment: @JimL I know that can use existing services for backup but I wanted to do it by my own. Even if I order a server for just storing clients backups there is risk that that server could be hacked also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165405/discussion-between-freelightman-and-jiml).